# Access Passed Parameters MVC Xhttp.Send()

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am working on a MVC based  WEBAPI project in c#.
I have a json object `dataToSend` (JSON FORMAT) that has to be passed to the API.

The API seems to be working fine since it returns what it is expected to. However I want to access the data send to it from `xhttp.send(dataToSend)` .

Here's the frontend code:

```
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        var selectedOptions = ["1","2","3"];
        var searchQuery = "Text Of Choice" ;

        var dataToSend = {
            searchQuery: searchQuery,
            attributes: selectedOptions
        }

        console.log(dataToSend);
        var postUrl = "/home/post";
        for (i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
            console.log(selectedOptions[i]);
        }


        xhttp.open("POST", "/home/post/", true);
        xhttp.send(dataToSend);
```

I am unable to figure out how to access `dataToSend` in my `POST` API call.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public string Post()
        {
            var dataToRecieve = ..... ??
            return "posted";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend first creating a model for the object u will be receiving like:

```
 public class SearchModel
 {
     public string   SearchQuery;
     public string[] selectedOptions;
 }
```

then receive the object as a FromBody Parameter:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] SearchModel model)
    {
        var dataToRecieve = model
        return Ok(dataToReceive);
    }
```

the [FromBody] means that u will be receiving the parameters from the request body